# docker-compose fails on host mashine

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker-compose

I have a few microservices runins on spring boot, each of them have they own postgres database. When I run `docker-compose up` on development windows mashin it works correctly. But when I deploy it on linux VPS host,  spring can not connect to database. Individually (without environment variables) the images are launched on VPS.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
 gateway:
  image: gateway:latest
  container_name: gateway
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  environment:
    - DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/gateway_db
    - DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
    - DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
    - JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
    - postgres

 postgres:
  image: postgres:14.4
  container_name: gateway_db
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: "gateway_db"
    POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  expose:
    - 5432
  healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d postgres" ]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 5
    start_period: 10s
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
    - postgres

volumes:
  pgdata:

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

And this is my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=${DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=${JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO}
```

So, [here's spring logs](https://pastebin.com/Rm7ujC3D) from docker container on host machine

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: in the log  java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres seem that postgres is not known  as host  in the  linux VPS host , i will as first test going with the ip of postgres. Then check it why postgres is not recognized  as host

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. Now I have direction where to dig

Comment: Why are you defining dedicated network in your compose file? Do you have containers not related to that running cluster assuming to operate in the same network? I'm asking because compose creates network for each run. Try to remove networks from your compose file and check if the issue will persist.

Comment: Honestly, because of tutorial. And because it worked on dev laptop didn't even think about it